# Can Netbeans be used as an IDE for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, sinatra

Preface: I'm a big fan of Netbeans for Rails development.

I'm just starting my first Sinatra app and it doesn't look like Netbeans provides any IDE support for Sinatra development.

Has anyone discovered a solution or did I just miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An IDE? You're just going to need a text editor with Ruby syntax highlighting.

Sinatra is meant to be a thin layer on top of Rack, so there just aren't that many Sinatra-specific features to learn. You'll be okay without any IDE help. Just check the [documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/book.html). The official documentation is still spotty, so be sure to read the [source](http://www.sinatrarb.com/api/index.html) too. It's compact and easy to understand.